# Where can I find community governance info for Cardano?

Tags: governance, community

I recently spoke to some other members in the Cardano community and I'd like to know more about governance. For example how the community can engage in meaningful discussions about the protocol and how it should and can be governed by the community. Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn about the [CIP](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs) process is to review the [CIP1: CIP process](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip1/).

Discussion is mostly happening on the CIP github using the pull requests but also on bi-weekly [CIP](https://www.crowdcast.io/cips-biweekly) meetings.

Answer (score 1):

[Project Catalyst](https://cardano.ideascale.com/) is Cardano's first major Governance product. You can submit proposals for new tools, features or improvements during the submission period of a fund cycle.

[This](https://cardanocataly.st/) is a community-built dashboard that aggregates a lot of important info about Catalyst.